# Cursor procedure skipping all rows and fetching last row data for each iteration

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

**Have to display Grades of each salary according to reference amount declared**

**For : sal<1000 grade 'D'
sal between 1000 and 3000 grade 'C'
sal between 3000 and 5000 grade 'B'
and sal > 5000 grade 'A'**

**Sample Table**

```
+-------+---------+-----------+------+------------+---------+---------+--------+
| EMPNO | ENAME   | JOB       | MGR  | HIREDATE   | SAL     | COMM    | DEPTNO |
+-------+---------+-----------+------+------------+---------+---------+--------+
|  7369 | SMITH   | CLERK     | 7902 | 1980-12-17 | 1040.00 |    NULL |     20 |
|  7499 | ALLEN   | SALESMAN  | 7698 | 1981-02-20 | 3440.00 |  300.00 |     30 |
|  7521 | WARD    | SALESMAN  | 7698 | 1981-02-22 | 2687.50 |  500.00 |     30 |
|  7566 | JONES   | MANAGER   | 7839 | 1981-04-02 | 2975.00 |    NULL |     20 |
|  7698 | BLAKE   | MANAGER   | 7839 | 1981-05-01 | 2850.00 |    NULL |     30 |
|  7782 | CLARK   | MANAGER   | 7839 | 1981-06-09 | 2450.00 |    NULL |     10 |
|  7788 | SCOTT   | ANALYST   | 7566 | 1982-12-09 | 3000.00 |    NULL |     20 |
|  7839 | KING    | PRESIDENT | NULL | 1981-11-17 | 5000.00 |    NULL |     10 |
|  7844 | TURNER  | SALESMAN  | 7698 | 1981-09-08 | 1500.00 |    0.00 |     30 |
|  7902 | FORD    | ANALYST   | 7566 | 1981-12-03 | 3000.00 |    NULL |     20 |
|  7934 | MILLER  | CLERK     | 7782 | 1982-01-23 | 1300.00 |    NULL |     10 |
|  1501 | swapnil | MANAGER   | NULL | 1989-05-22 | 5050.00 |    1000 |     20 |
+-------+---------+-----------+------+------------+---------+---------+--------+
```

**But Cursor is selecting last row salary for each iteration and skips all other row data in fetch don't know the cause**

**Code**

```
delimiter $$
create procedure grading_sal()
begin
    declare psal decimal(9,2) default 0;
    declare pgrade varchar(2); 
    declare v_stop int default 0;
    declare pempno int default 0;
    declare empcur cursor for select sal
    from employee;
    declare continue handler for NOT FOUND
    set v_stop=1;
    alter table employee
    add column grade varchar(2);
open empcur;
lable1: loop
    fetch empcur into psal, pempno;
if(v_stop=1)
then
    leave lable1;
end if;
if psal<1000 
then
    set pgrade = 'D';
elseif psal<2999
then
    set pgrade = 'C';
elseif psal<4999
then
    set pgrade = 'B';
else
    set pgrade = 'A';
end if;
    update employee
    set grade = pgrade;
end loop;
    select empno,ename,hiredate,sal,grade,deptno
    from employee
    where deptno=10;
close empcur;
end $$
delimiter ;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
mysql> call grading_sal()
+-------+--------+------------+---------+-------+--------+
| empno | ename  | hiredate   | sal     | grade | deptno |
+-------+--------+------------+---------+-------+--------+
|  7782 | CLARK  | 1981-06-09 | 2450.00 | A     |     10 |
|  7839 | KING   | 1981-11-17 | 5000.00 | A     |     10 |
|  7934 | MILLER | 1982-01-23 | 1300.00 | A     |     10 |
+-------+--------+------------+---------+-------+--------+
3 rows in set (0.08 sec)
```

Comment: A few things, you don't need a procedure to do this, it is way simpler to use some `case` statements` in a query; don't use a DDL (`alter`) command in a procedure if it runs more than one it will fail the next time as the change is already applied; lastly your problem is because you are processing the `grade` and updating THE WHOLE TABLE, no `where`  statement for the row you need to update.

Answer (score 1):

I've added a comment but thought it is good enough for an answer so:

A few things, 1- you don't need a procedure to do this, it is way simpler to use some `case` statements in a query;

Don't use a DDL (alter) command in a procedure if it runs more than once it will fail the next time as the change is already applied;

Lastly your problem is because you are processing the grade and updating THE WHOLE TABLE, no where statement for the row you need to update. Here: `update employee set grade = pgrade;` running it in the loop doesn't mean it will update that specific row in the loop.

So here is the query you would use:

```
select empno,ename,hiredate,sal,
       case when sal < 1000 then 'D' 
            when sal >= 1000 and sal < 3000 then 'C'
            when sal >= 3000 and sal < 5000 then 'B'
            when sal >= 5000 then 'B' end as grade,
       ,deptno
    from employee
    where deptno=10;
```

If you really need to add the value to the column, just use an update:

```
-- add the column just once
alter table employee
    add column grade varchar(2);

-- run the update just once
update employee
   set grade = case when sal < 1000 then 'D' 
            when sal >= 1000 and sal < 3000 then 'C'
            when sal >= 3000 and sal < 5000 then 'B'
            when sal >= 5000 then 'A' end;
```